# What are the elements of $Z[x]/\langle x^2 - 1\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a hard time visualizing what the actual elements of this ring are. Because it is mod the elements generated by $x^2 - 1$ are polynomials with non-even powers in the ring or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of the ring can be thought of as the polynomials $a+bx$ of degree $\le 1$, with the "normal" addition, and multiplication almost normal, except that $x^2$ is replaced by $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1)$, and $x+1$ and $x-1$ are both irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Thus by the Chinese Remainder Theorem we have
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2 - 1 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x+1 \rangle \times\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x-1 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}
\end{equation}
So this ring is just integer pairs. Does that answer your question?

Comment: This is *misleading*. The Chinese remainder theorem does not work the way you suggest it does when the coefficient ring is $\mathbf Z$ rather than a field. The natural ring homomorphism  from ${\mathbf Z}[x]/(x^2-1)$ to ${\mathbf Z} \times {\mathbf Z}$ by $f(x) \bmod x^2-1 \mapsto (f(-1),f(1))$ is injective but *not* surjective. For example, if $f(x) \bmod x^2-1 \mapsto (1,0)$ then from $f(1) = 0$ we get $f(x) = (x-1)g(x)$ in ${\mathbf Z}[x]$, and that implies $f(-1) = -2g(-1)$ is even, so $f(-1)$ can't be $1$. The correct image is all pairs $(a,b)$ where $a \equiv b \bmod 2$.

Comment: You are correct. My mistake. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: If the image is a = b mod 2, does this mean that idempotents in this field are just the pairs (0,1) and (1,0) representing the pairs e, 1-e?